# xtable geoip filter unable to load into memroy

Tags: iptables, centos6

Ok,

I have a odd problem. I just got done doing the bas configuring of my server. Adding in fail2ban, postfix, apache, mysql, ect ect.

I then went in and started to add the xtable addons. I downloaded version `1.47.1` as that is the version (to my knowledge) the lastest version for my kernel `2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64`

After compiling with IPv6 options disabled, compiling with has always thrown errors for me, I went in updated my geoip database made sure the BE and LE folder were in `/usr/share/xt_geoip` and added this filter:

```
-A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc US -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable
```

But when I did i got this message:

```
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

The last entry in dmesg was this:

```
xt_geoip: unable to load 'US' into memory: -12
```

So at the moment i'm stuck. This is the first time on any of my servers I have run into this problem. Granted this my first CentOS 6 server, all my past servers have used Centos 5.

I do know where in the code the error is coming from (line 86 in the xt_geoip.c file), but I know that would be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your compiled files aren't empty.  I had the same error after following instructions from here:

http://terminal28.com/how-to-block-countries-using-iptables-debian/

...and found the iv6 files had data, but the .iv4 ones were all empty, I think because I was missing the "unzip" package when first run.

Checked to confirm there was data in the .CSV files, ran this command to re-build:

```
 ./xt_geoip_build -D /usr/share/xt_geoip *.csv
```

...and was able to use country codes with iptables immediately.